# How to properly download PDF as a server response

Tags: java, rest, http, pdf, curl

I need help with correct way how to save PDF file. I use HttpClient from Java 11. I send authorization request on the server and then i get content-type=[application/pdf] response from server. But when I save the response as a PDF, the PDF file is empty. I think that the structure of PDF is ok, because it has 4 empty page.When I open a PDF file code, it is full of question marks and random characters.

It looks like this:

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
3 0 obj
<</ColorSpace/DeviceGray/Subtype/Image/Height 59/Filter/FlateDecode/Type/XObject/Width 250/Length 2527/BitsPerComponent 8>>stream
x��[{XUU���(��Lㄓ9>�F�h|���3Q1�1�tr�ѱ�JEE ˴Q���F��ŗѧ�O4)h|K6 >y�)��眵��{�}�9��K��ǽ�Zk��;���Z�\-�_%����fvaiUMեo��]7����"_s�.�p�pJ���y�t�g�Q�5����k6D���VP����Cl��>o��eӣ�?M�Fh���lrL�n�8��@����F�wΎ�i�s�,��jӢO�Y�(�ٱ6)�&�Vӎ���F���������� ����>�5OM�=��W]M]y�^�$u���E�Nl���z��R� qԇvMA����W�?�]�h���c����R��"��sV��ĐШ)/��MYT2w}�4�����a_oa�qd�n�~UY�ի6
o�������OO���Jw
...
...
...
0001204416 00000 n 
0001204779 00000 n 
0001205451 00000 n 
0001205497 00000 n 
trailer
<</Info 33 0 R/ID [<649ae65d919544aa64f7a389364ee40b><e69ed04604543e762e4be5cfb2db490f>]/Root 32 0 R/Size 34>>
startxref
1205620
%%EOF
```

My class look like this:

```
public class Test_pdf {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                .build();

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("https://example.com/client/clientnumber/ident-pdf"))
                .GET()
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer 123456789")
                .build();

        HttpResponse<Path> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofFile(Paths.get("C:\\test.pdf")));
    }
}
```

I try byte array with:

```
        HttpResponse<byte[]> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArray());

        File file = new File("C:\\test.pdf");

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);

        os.write(response.body());
        System.out.println("Successfully");

        os.close();
```

I tried to download the file directly using the cURL command, but the file was the same problem.

```
curl -v -N https://example.com/client/clientnumber/ident-pdf ^ -H "Authorization: Bearer 123456789" --output test.pdf
```

It's my first work with PDF documents. Do I miss some encoding in my code? Or what could be the cause of the wrong PDF?

Thank you.

Comment: That's what a PDF file *should* look like if you open it in a text editor.  You should be opening it using a PDF viewer of some kind.

Comment: You might try setting the `responseType='application/pdf'`

Comment: When I open a PDF file in a browser or Adobe Acrobat it contains only 4 blank pages. When I open another PDF in the editor, there are normal characters without question marks or squares. So I think that PDF contains unknown characters that PDF viewer can't handle. But i dont know why.

`responseType='application/pdf'` I tried but no change. The server response is application/pdf type.

Comment: Are you still struggling with this @Petero?